# SSIS 2008 - How to extract unicode characters and be left with a non unicode string

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SSIS 2008 R2.

I want to take a unicode string, extract all the "unicode only" characters so I am left with a "non unicode" string.

In my case, it should be mostly control characters, CR, LF etc etc.

Is there an easy way to do this without a replace sequence a mile long?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want at all. There is a function [unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) in T-SQL that returns the unicode integer value for a character. If you by "unicode only" mean characters with a unicode integer value greater than 255 you can use this code to get a string without the "unicode" characters.

```
declare @str nvarchar(5)
declare @str2 nvarchar(5)

set @str  = 'A'+nchar(300)+'B'+nchar(400)+'C'
set @str2 = ''

;with cte as
(
  select
    left(@str, 1) as val,
    stuff(@str, 1, 1, '') as rest
  union all  
  select
    left(rest, 1) as val,
    stuff(rest, 1, 1, '') as rest
  from cte
  where len(rest) > 0  
)
select @str2 = @str2 + val
from cte  
where unicode(val) < 256 

print @str
print @str2
```

Result

```
AĬBƐC
ABC
```